# Best way to persist soap request and response into Oracle database?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, soap, persistence

I want to track service calls for security reasons into database and I need to generate reports above them. I don't know what is the best way, using soap handlers, using database loggers or something else but I know that performance is very important for me.
Any Idea? 
P.S javaee

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the traffic amount you get on your web services, it might not be a good idea to make a database write per request. Instead what you should do is make some kind of a listener that is triggered each time a ws request comes in, to which you'd pass the request itself, and then  that listener will cache back several reports based on those requests, and then write them all to the db at certain intervals (like every 10 minutes, each night at 3 a.m., etc)